# ActiveCollab 2.3.1: Using SVN integration

Tags: php, mysql, svn, iis, visualsvn-server

We're a Windows shop, but have set-up **ActiveCollab** installed under IIS using a PHP plug-in and having set-up a MySQL database server.

I've just **upgraded up to the latest version of ActiveCollab (2.3.1)**, but I'm having difficultly getting the SVN integration working.

As shown in the screenshot here: (http://www.avonandsomerset.police.uk/secure/ActiveCollabSVN.png) **I can't get ActiveCollab to find the svn executable.**

We've got VisualSVN Server installed on the same server of ActiveCollab, which has the svn.exe under the "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin" location shown in the screenshot.

I've tried specifying:

- C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin
- file://C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin

Plus added '**C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin**' under the Windows PATH settings, but nothing seems to work.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be most grateful.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 2):

If it can be usefull to someone : I found that changing the slashes in config.php solves the issue:

```
 define('ROOT', 'D:\\www\\activecollab');
```

Change it to :

```
 define('ROOT', 'D:/www/activecollab');
```

Gus

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if your 'C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin' folder has the right permissions set up so PHP server can access svn.exe file?